# Digital Ocean Load Balancer http to https with 301 instead of 307

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, digital-ocean

in my setup I have a DigitalOcean load balancer connected with only one droplet(for now) running nginx. I Manage my SSL certificate with the load balancer via [SSL Termination](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/load-balancers/how-to/ssl-termination/). The Load Balancer has this forwarding rules set up:

HTTP on port 80  ->  HTTP on port 80

HTTP2 on port 443  ->  HTTP on port 80

There is an option for the load Balancer to Redirect HTTP to HTTPS. But if I use this option it uses an 307 redirect instead of an 301. According to DigitalOcean this is intended. I was told for Seo reasons it should be using a 301. I tried to disable the option and redirect using nginx configs but i ended up in a infinity loop. This is the snipped i used:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;
        # $scheme will get the http protocol
        # and 301 is best practice for tablet, phone, desktop and seo
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Does anyone know how to properly handle this situation? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers
Raph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured it out i could prevent the loop with adding

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

as suggested in this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/502733/rewrite-http-to-https-with-ngnix-behind-load-balancer)